# How to pass list of Django form field names to template?

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, view

I have a very basic form:

```
class NavigationForm(forms.Form):
    NavSelection1 = forms.TextInput()
```

In my view I want to pass a list to the template:

```
form = NavigationForm()
context['formfields'] = [i for i in form.fields]
return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

I am hoping to be able to use:

```
{% for i in formfields %}
    {{i}}
{% endfor %}
```

But it returns nothing.

```
{{formfields}}
```

Alone returns an empty list

```
[]
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I'm stumped at the moment.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the form didn't like TextInput()

I changed it to CharField() and it passes all the form information I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing forms like this

```
form = NavigationForm()
context['form'] = form
return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

Then in your template

```
{{form}}
```

Or maybe you want to do this

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: For some reason my scenario doesn't return any values doing that.